# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{k}}$$

I tried to write the sum above as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n+1}}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{2n}}$$
Now if I solve the limit the result is $0$ but obviously it's wrong. I think because it's an infinity sum of factors that go to zero, but it could be that the sum goes to infinity faster than the factors so that the result isn't zero. However I don't know how to solve it. Some advice?

Answer (score 4):

For $1\le n\le k\le2n$ we have

$$n+1\le n+\sqrt{k}\le n+\sqrt{2n}\le n+1+\sqrt{2n+2}$$

hence

$${1\over1+\sqrt{2\over n+1}}={n+1\over n+1+\sqrt{2n+2}}\le\sum_{k=n}^{2n}{1\over n+\sqrt k}\le{n+1\over n+1}=1$$

The Squeeze Theorem does the rest.

Comment: ${n + 1 \over n + \,\sqrt{\,2n\,}\,} < \sum < {n + 1 \over n + \,\sqrt{\,n\,}\,}$ ia a shortest proof.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{n +\sqrt{k}} \leq \frac{1}{n}$, so the sum is upper-bounded by $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \ldots \frac{1}{n} = 1 $

Comment: There are $n+1$ terms, not $n$, but the idea is still the same

Comment: And it's lower-bounded by $(n+1)/(n+\sqrt{2n})$.

Answer (score 1):

This sum is $$1+\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{k=n}^{2n}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{k}})\approx 1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\sqrt{k}\approx 1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\int_n^{2n}x^{-1/2}dx\in 1+\mathcal (\frac{1}{n}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Use "sandwich theorem": $\displaystyle{n + 1 \over n + \,\sqrt{\,2n\,}\,} < \sum < {n + 1 \over n + \,\sqrt{\,n\,}\,}$.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a small Python code to calculate this sum for specific $n$ values, to see where the limit of $n \to \infty$ goes:

```
import math

def limit(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n,2*n+1):
        s += 1/(n+math.sqrt(i))
    return s

for a in range(1,10001):
    print "n = " + str(a) + " | limit = " + str(limit(a))

print "n = 1000000 | limit = " + str(limit(1000000))
print "n = 10000000 | limit = " + str(limit(10000000))
```

Its output was

```
n = 1 | limit = 0.914213562373
n = 2 | limit = 0.810842411245
n = 3 | limit = 0.785811290103
n = 4 | limit = 0.778993834934
n = 5 | limit = 0.778479980466
n = 6 | limit = 0.780536268748
n = 7 | limit = 0.783702898
n = 8 | limit = 0.787331118896
n = 9 | limit = 0.791109376332
n = 10 | limit = 0.794881504095
```

$\vdots$

```
n = 9990 | limit = 0.988051600225
n = 9991 | limit = 0.988052185976
n = 9992 | limit = 0.988052771641
n = 9993 | limit = 0.988053357219
n = 9994 | limit = 0.988053942711
n = 9995 | limit = 0.988054528116
n = 9996 | limit = 0.988055113434
n = 9997 | limit = 0.988055698666
n = 9998 | limit = 0.988056283811
n = 9999 | limit = 0.988056868869
n = 10000 | limit = 0.988057453841
n = 1000000 | limit = 0.998783545517
n = 10000000 | limit = 0.99961478362
```

From this, it seems to very slowly approach $1$.